# Facebook Graph API works in web browser, not in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I tried this in my web browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<facebookID>/statuses?access_token=<my access token>
```

And I thought in iOS SDK this is the equivalent of that query:

```
NSString* graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/statuses",facebookID];
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPath andDelegate:self];
```

But that returns an empty JSON data... Am I doing something wrong in here? Other queries seems fine to me (e.g. `@"me"`, `@"me/statuses"`, `@"me/friends"`)

I think this is also documented in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

**More info:**

I have read_stream permission

Comment: do you have read_streams permission?

Comment: Yes I do. In fact doing @"<friendID>/feed" works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... I need "friend_statuses" permission! I did not know that! =)